# Why do I get error in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a query from view table in `phpMyAdmin`. When I tried to do query, the result was error. Here is my query:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`=`Perempuan`) AS `Perempuan`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`=`Laki-laki`) AS `Laki-laki`
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

**The error message is**

`#1054 - Unknown column 'Perempuan' in 'field list'`

I use `left join` in my view table. Here is my view table named **jeniskelaminreal**

[image]

What may I do so that I can get the result? Thank you in advance

Comment: Check CASE syntax `CASE WHEN JenisKelamin='Perempuan' THEN ... ELSE .. END`

Comment: The code is pretty obviously MySQL so I removed the SQL Server tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` statement is missing `ELSE` part and back quote is also a problem, so it should be like this.

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS `Perempuan`,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Laki-laki' THEN 1 END) AS `Laki-laki`
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using backticks instead of double quotes while comparing the value. Also, your `CASE` statements are missing `THEN` and `END`, try the following:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS 'Perempuan',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Laki-laki' THEN 1 END) AS 'Laki-laki'
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `case` has the following syntax:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`= 'Perempuan' THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS `Perempuan`
```

or since the `else` part is `null` by default:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`= 'Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS `Perempuan`
```

In MySQL you could also do

```
SUM(JenisKelamin = 'Perempuan') AS `Perempuan`
```

Also string are delimited by quotes and not backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `THEN` and `END` keywords.  Also, the *string* constants need to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN JenisKelamin = 'Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS `Perempuan`,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN JenisKelamin = 'Laki-laki' THEN 1 END) AS `Laki-laki`
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

MySQL (which you appear to be using) has a convenient shorthand:

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
       SUM(CJenisKelamin = 'Perempua') AS Perempuan,
       SUM(JenisKelamin = 'Laki-laki') AS `Laki-laki`
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace ` with ' in `'Perempuan'` and `'Laki-laki'`

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS 'Perempuan',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Laki-laki' THEN 1 END) AS 'Laki-laki'
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

Answer (score 0):

as per mysql documentation the syntax is

```
CASE case_value
WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
[WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
[ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

**or**

```
CASE
WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
[WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
[ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

[READ HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

your query look like this

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Perempuan' THEN 1 END) AS 'Perempuan',
COUNT(CASE WHEN `JenisKelamin`='Laki-laki' THEN 1 END) AS 'Laki-laki'
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```

and also you can do this way by using `field()` with `sum()` to count those results

```
SELECT TahunMasuk, 
SUM(FIELD(JenisKelamin,Perempuan)) AS 'Perempuan',
SUM(FIELD(JenisKelamin,Laki-laki)) AS 'Laki-laki'
FROM jeniskelaminreal
GROUP BY TahunMasuk;
```